# Blank lines in a .csv files created through SSMS :OUT command

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm using code like this in MSSQL 2008 R2 management Studio to write the results of a SELECT statement to a csv file on a network share:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;   
GO    
:OUT \\163.123.45.678\SomeFolder\mydata.csv    
SELECT id, name, surname FROM sometable;    
GO
```

This creates the `mydata.csv` file at the correct location but there is an extra blank line at the end of the csv file. How do I prevent that blank line from being created in the csv file?

Is the above the best way to write the output of a sql query to a text file? I can't use BCP.

Thanks.

Comment: I see the same results here whenever I run this. My thought is that this is "just the way it works". Can use use SSIS?

Comment: It seems that the blank line is part of the "x rows affected" message that would be displayed if NOCOUNT is OFF.

Comment: @coge.soft, the syntax he is using (e.g. :OUT blah) is SQLCMD being run through SSMS.

Comment: Are you sure that this is an extra blank line and not just the result of a carriage return /line feed at the end of the last line? Do you have trouble re importing the file? Is another process complaining about the line?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use SSIS package to get the query result in .CSV format. sometime you may get blank line or space in between two lisne, in that case 'Derived Column' transformation task and remove or trim the unwanted spaces and lines.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following from the command prompt?

```
C:\>sqlcmd -S SQLServerHost -W -Q "SET NOCOUNT ON; SELECT TOP 5 date_id, previous_date, next_date FROM dates WHERE month_key = 201212" > testNoLine.txt
```

The result:

[image]

The generated file has no extra line at the bottom (unlike the SSMS execution).

Comment: The MSDN link (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773(v=sql.105).aspx) is not providing a switch for the W parameter. Another reason for a difference is OLE DB vs .Net client - maybe one of them is returning an extra line all the time?

Answer (score 0):

In the end using a SSIS package was a much better solution.